# Images with missing src

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to make if statement where I check every image if it has missing src ( not empty but missing ) and if this case is true to add it with some path in it.

Comment: What have you tried ? Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let path = '/img.png';

$('img').each(function(){
   if($(this).attr('src') === undefined){
    $(this).attr('src',path);
   }
})
```